# Unexpected token in operand movl

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, apple-m1

I'm writing a simple .s file but when I compile with

```
gcc main.c f.s -o out -m32
```

I get the following error

```
f.s:3:15: error: unexpected token in operand
    movl $10, %eax
              ^
f.s:4:5: error: invalid instruction
    ret
    ^
```

that's the sketch

```
.globl f
f:
    movl $10, %eax
    ret
```

where is the problem?
I'm running on an m1 MacBook Pro

Comment: Are you compiling for x86 instead of ARM64?  I'd expect the native `gcc` command (which is actually clang on a Mac) to target ARM64 by default on an ARM64 system.  When you run `gcc -m32 -v main.c foo.s`, what Target does it say it's compiling for?